# Visual Studio 2010 debug in a fixed port

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, webdev.webserver

Is it possible to choose a fixed port for the Visual Studio 2010 debug webserver?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If it's similar to VS2008, you can do the following to fix the port number:

1. Click on the web site project node in Solution Explorer
2. Hit <kbd>F4</kbd> to bring up the properties tool window
3. Set "Use dynamic ports" to false
4. Set "Port number" to whatever you need

Answer (score 9):

Should appear as an option in the web project properties, 'Web' tab. By default its set to auto-assign but theres an option to set a specific port.