# Visual Studio 2010 Specific port is modified!

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2010

In my ASP.NET MVC Application project, I set the option "Specific port" and set it to 80, but the VS 2010 always chooses a differnt random port number of me.

What do I do to make it keep the port I selected?

Comment: maybe because port 80 is the default web server port? probably a conflict...choose another port.

Comment: Yes, that was correct. I thought I needed 80 to test a facebook app, but no. Changing the hosts file was enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this particular problem was using a different port. I managed to use the 80 port through IIS, but that was another option.

Answer (score 1):

See this thread Fabio:

[Visual Studio 2010 debug in a fixed port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920610/visual-studio-2010-debug-in-a-fixed-port)

Comment: think that only works for "Web Sites", not "Web Applications". MVC uses "Web Applications".