# IIS Express 7.5 refuses to launch from VS 2K10 Ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, iis-express

When trying to debug a web project from VS 2010 Ultimate using IIS Express I get the following error:
"Unable to launch IIS Express Web Server."

IIS Express does start when this error appears and I can navigate the working site via a web browser.
It appears that VS is not attaching to the web server.

I can launch IIS Express from the command line without errors.

I have tried IIS Express 7.5 and 8 (beta) with the same result.

The project launches fine using the VS Development Server.

Comment: Any errors in the Event logs? Did you select "Use IIS Express" in the solution explorer?

Comment: Nothing that stood out to me in the Event logs.
Yes, "Use IIS Express" is checked.

Comment: Does it run if you launch it from Visual Studio in elevated mode (Run as Admin)?

Comment: Can you try the recommendations in this topic? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171656/unable-to-launch-the-iis-express-web-server

Comment: Running as Admin gives the same result.

Comment: I have tried those recommendations with no change in the result.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue.  Please post a resolution if you find one.  In my case, this only occurs on my work machine (Win 7 Enterprise x64, VS2010 Ultimate with SP1, IIS Express 7.5.1190).  I noticed that when running a "Web Site" (vs Web Application), the error message indicates that the iisexpress.exe process does not exist or has exited, even though it's clearly visible in Task Manager.

Comment: I'm having the same issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762646/debugging-mvc-application-in-vs2012-attempts-to-start-iis-express-twice

I've written a bug up at Microsoft Connect.  Please vote it up to help get this issue resolved: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/778864/vs2012-is-spawning-two-iisexpress-processes-when-attempting-to-debug

Comment: Try to reboot the machine with VS and also try to set the particular port that's not used by any daemon, see here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920610/visual-studio-2010-debug-in-a-fixed-port

Comment: IIS Express issues are not related to IIS. Don't use IIS tag.

Answer (score 0):

Attempt #1:

- Uninstall IIS Express
- Install IIS Express 7.5
- Install IIS Express 8.0

Attempt #2:

- Go to C:\Users\\Documents\IISExpress\config and change your IIS Version on  node to 4.0.30319

Reference: [Link](http://roykimsharepoint.wordpress.com/2012/11/10/issue-visual-studio-2012-unable-to-launch-the-iis-express-web-server/)

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem in vs2012, but solved it by:

unistall IIS

unistall VS2010

install VS2013